# Fallo de codigo al ejecutar la función

Tags: c

Muy buenos días estoy recién empezando a programar con 'c' y hay veces que tengo dudas que quizas sean tonterías pero como en todo cuando empiezas, estoy pidiendo al usuario me diga cuantos dígitos quiere en un arreglo para despues rellenarlo con dígitos con un bucle for. a la hora de rellenarlo lo hago con una función que coge como argumentos la longitud del arreglo que se preguntó al usuario, he probado a borrar la memoria con `fflush( stdin );` pero la verdad que no me arranca la función, os dejo el código a ver si me podéis orientar. salu2

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void func1(int n);
char lista[10];
void func1(int n){
    int numero;
    int i;
      for (i==1;i<=n;i++){
          printf("digite un numero: \n");
          scanf("%i",&numero);
          
          lista[i]=numero;
     printf("%s",lista);
     
 }
 }
   int main()
  {
    


 int n1;
printf("digite cuantos numeros quiere en la lista: ");
scanf("%i\n",&n1);
func1(n1);


return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Vayamos por partes...

1. En el bucle `for` tienes un error. No puedes decir `i==1`, porque estás comparando en vez de asignar a la variable `i` el valor 1. Debe ser de la forma `i=1`. Por otro lado, te recomiendo empezar con el subíndice `0`, ya que en C los arrays empiezan en 0. En otros lenguajes como por ejemplo Matlab sí se empieza con el subíndice 1.
2. Quieres almacenar números, pues te recomiendo trabajar con `int` (o `uint8_t` si tienes restricción de que tu variable sea de 1Byte, en cuyo caso deberás incluir la librería `stdint.h`) en vez de trabajar con `char` ya que es para caracteres. Por lo tanto tu array `lista` yo lo definiría como `uint8_t lista[10]`. Otro apunte (**RECOMENDACIÓN**), una vez que sepas el tamaño del array podrías crear dicho array, ya que sino siempre tendrás 10 elementos a poner y estarás o desperdiciando memoria o incluso desbordar si el usuario quiere poner más de 10 números. Todo esto en vez de crear tu array como variable global al principio del programa (fuera del `main`).
3. No pongas `\n` en la función `scanf()` porque te dará error. El salto de línea es automático.
4. La lista te interesa imprimirla una vez que ya tengas todos los números insertados, por lo que sería conveniente sacarlo del bucle `for` donde rellenas dicho array. Además, si cambiamos como te digo el tipo de datos del array, lo suyo es emplear otro bucle `for` para que recorra todas las posiciones del array y mostrar así todos sus datos.

Son errores bastante comunes que hemos tenido todos cuando empezamos a programar. No desistas porque lo estás haciendo genial.

El código que buscas se puede parecer a algo parecido a esto:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void func1(int n);

uint8_t lista[10];

void func1(int n)
{
    int numero;
    int i;

    for (i=0 ; i<n ; i++)
    {
        printf("digite un numero: ");
        scanf("%i", &numero);
        lista[i]=numero;
    }
    // Imprimimos array
    printf (" LA LISTA: ");
    for (i=0 ; i<n ; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", lista[i]);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n1;
    printf("digite cuantos numeros quiere en la lista: ");
    scanf("%i", &n1);
    func1(n1);

    return 0;
}
```